# Union of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My Analysis professor mentioned the following theorem: If a sequence $(a_n)$ is the union of finitely many disjoint subsequences, and if all the subsequences converge to $l$,then sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $l$.
I'm not entirely sure whether this language is appropriate. Could someone correct it/help me understand?

Comment: Sequences are functions which in turn are sets and union of sets should be nothing weird to you.

Comment: I understand. But will the union of sequences in turn give you a well defined sequence?

Comment: In general no, but the union of functions with disjoint domains is a function.

Comment: Exactly. So if you consider the union of the odd and even subsequences a2n-1 and a2n,which are an instance of 'disjoint'sequences my teacher cited,their union won't necessarily yield a sequence will it?

Comment: You're right. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequences are functions which in turn are sets and union of sets is nothing weird. The union of functions need not be a function. A sufficient, but not necessary condition for the union of functions to be a function is that the domains are disjoint.

As the OP has pointed out in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967805/union-of-sequences#comment1987193_967805) comment, the union of disjoint subsequences of a given sequence $a$ need not be a sequence. Below is an example of this.

Recall that a subsequence of $a$ is a sequence of the form $a\circ \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers.

Let $a=\text{id}_{\mathbb N}, \alpha=\{(n,2n)\colon n\in \mathbb N\}$ and $\beta=\{(n,2n-1)\colon n\in \mathbb N\}$. One gets $a\circ \alpha=\alpha, a\circ \beta=\beta$ and clearly $\alpha\cup \beta$ is not a function despite $\alpha \cap \beta=\varnothing$, that is, the union of the subsequences $a\circ \alpha$ and $a\circ \beta$ is not a sequence.

What the author of the problem should have said is "if $a$ has the property that finitely many of its subsequences $a\circ\alpha _1, \ldots ,a\circ \alpha _n$ are such that the range of any pair of $\alpha _k$'s is disjoint and the union of all the ranges of $\alpha_k$'s is $\mathbb N$ (which is the domain) of $a$, then ..."

Comment: I opted to avoid my usual way of writing mathematics because I feel like its more in accordance to the style used in the original text.

Comment: One question. What does the ○ indicate? Composition of functions?

Comment: And shouldn't the first two "codomains" be replaced by the term range to make it less ambiguous, and the third "codomain" be replaced by domain?

Comment: And even so,it is not necessary that the union is a sequence.

Comment: Yes, $\circ$ denotes function composition, it's standard notation. The term codomain is also standard to refer to the range and you're right, I meant 'domain of $a$'. Finally, regarding your last comment, I had made a mistake in my answer and fixed it.

Comment: I wouldn't say they are interchangeable, as disjoint codomains implies disjoint ranges but not vice versa. But yes,I understand your point. Thanks.

Comment: @RaghavTalwar I'm sorry, in elementary set theory (which is usually where my mind is at) codomain and range are the same thing. It's not so here. I'll edit this. And you're welcome.